# Why this why to update Binding value work and second option don't work

Tags: swift, swiftui, data-binding, state

I'm try to delate and modify some "project" data in my view,
The view have a @Binding property Project, which is passed across different view.
In this current view I need to delate a picture tapped from an array of images in the Project, to do so I use a method with a closure which return to me my Project data.

Here the method:

```
 func delatePicture(imageToDel: ImageCustom, pp:Project?, closure: @escaping(Bool, _ imm: Project?)->()){
 //do stuff
}
```

Now when in my view I Tap to the picture to be delated I run the deletePicture method ,return the Project in the closure and update  the binding var  with this code:

```
.onLongPressGesture {
 am.delatePicture(imageToDel: item, pp: project) { isDone,proj  in
    guard let proj = proj else {
     return}
     // update the binding var project
   self.project = projf // not working
   }
}
```

The code I just wrote up here, NOT work, view want update , I need to exit and entry again to the view to see the change.

Now I kindly would like to know and understand why instead if I write the following code it work:

```
 .onLongPressGesture {
  am.delatePicture(imageToDel: item, pp: project) { isDone,proj  in
      guard let proj = proj else { return}
      let projf = Project(customId: proj.customId, name: proj.name, date: proj.date, images: proj.images, label: proj.label)
       projf.id = project!.id
       self.project = projf

  }
                                    
}
```

what is the mystery why my view don't update if I use the first code:

Here my view

```
struct ProjectView: View {
    @ObservedObject var am : AppManager
    @Binding var project : Project?
    let config = [
        GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    @State var picFrame : CGSize = CGSize( width: 300, height: 300)
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack{
                
                HStack{
                    Text("Project Name:")
                    Text(project?.name ?? "No Project").bold()
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Photos in Project")
                    Text("\(project?.images.count ?? 0)").bold()
                }.foregroundColor(.gray)
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: config, spacing: 10) {
                        
                        if project != nil {
                            ForEach(project!.images) { item in
                                VStack{
                                Image(uiImage: item.getImage()!)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .overlay{
                                        ForEach(item.labels) { cont in
                                            Path(cont.rect)
                                                .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: cont.getRectResize(size: picFrame).0, y: cont.getRectResize(size: picFrame).1))
                                                .stroke(Color(cont.label.color), lineWidth: 2)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .background(GeometryReader {
                                        Color.blue.preference(key: ViewRectKey.self,
                                                               value: [$0.frame(in: .global)])
                                    })
                                    if item.checkiffileExistAtPath(){
                                        Text("XML OK")
                                    } else {
                                        Text("XML Fail")
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                .onLongPressGesture {
                                    am.delatePicture(imageToDel: item, pp: project) { isDone,proj  in
                                        guard let proj = proj else {
                                            return
                                        }
                                        let projf = Project(customId: proj.customId, name: proj.name, date: proj.date, images: proj.images, label: proj.label)
                                        projf.id = project!.id
                                        self.project = projf

                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                
                                
                            }
    //                        .frame(width: geo.size.width/5, height: geo.size.height/5, alignment: .center)
                        } else {
                            Text("No Data Available")
                        }
                        
                        
                        Button {
                           
                            project = nil
                            
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "trash")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 18, height: 18, alignment: .center)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.padding()
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewRectKey.self) { rects in
                
                guard let rec = rects.first else {return}
                picFrame = CGSize(width: rec.width, height: rec.height)
//                print("rect \(rects)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If delete is asynchronous try to update project on main queue, like

```
.onLongPressGesture {
 am.delatePicture(imageToDel: item, pp: project) { isDone,proj  in
    guard let proj = proj else { return }

     // update the binding var project
    DispatchQueue.main.async {           // << here !!
       self.project = projf
    }
  }
}
```